# Reduce Aliasing in Modern UI

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

The aliasing on the on modern UI controls seems to be quite bad on my laptop (Intel "HD" graphics). I have tested two resolutions 1680x1050 (pictured) and 1366x768, in both cases the controls do not look smooth:

[image: Aliased back button]

Is there a way to improve the graphics quality?

Comment: Do you have ClearType enabled?

Comment: Is this a problem you experience in all apps or just some?
I've tried some apps where the buttons seemed grainy or pixelated, but e.g. the standard Windows apps look fine.

Comment: @BradPatton have tried turning cleartype on and off and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Phazyck seems to be all metro apps e.g. SkyDrive and Store. The circles look bad and the large heading e.g. 'Top Free' in the store doesn't look as crisp as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Maybe you could try this:

- Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to bring up a menu in the bottom left corner.
- Choose "System".
- In the left side of the new window, choose "Advanced System Settings."
- In the new window, go to the "Advanced" tab.
- Under the "Performance" section, click the "Settings..." button.
- You can now see and change your performance options.
- Try setting the options to "Adjust for best appearance".

Comment: All of the options are already selected

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. ClearType is disabled because it doesn't work fine when you rotate the screen:

http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120303/cleartype-takes-a-back-seat-for-windows-8-metro/

Comment: I thought ClearType was just for text? I am mostly interested in the graphics e.g. the circle in my screenshot.